# Bert Model not loading with pickle

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pytorch, pickle, bert-language-model

I trained a Bert Model for NER. It worked fine (obviously it took time to learn). I saved the model with `pickle` as

```
with open('model_pkl', 'wb') as file:
     pickle.dump(model, file)
```

When I am trying to load this saved model I am getting following error. `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'BertModel' on <module '__main__' from '<input>'>`. This method works for lists, dictionaries etc but producing error on `pytorch` model. I am using `python 3.8.10`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [torch.save and torch.load](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html#saving-and-loading-models-with-shapes).

Comment: what about this one, I have already trained this model

Comment: Try using torch.save instead of pickle.dump, and torch.load instead of pickle.load.